# class name and method name dropdown list is missing (visual studio setting)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2005

Does anyone know how to get my class name and method name dropdown lists again? It's the dropdown lists that are usually above the code. It's just a setting but i can't seem to find it. I don't want to reset my setting btw. I shouldn't have to.

Answer (score 273, accepted):

Tools-->Options...
Text Editor-->All Languages
Check "Navigation Bar."

[image: navBar]

(Picture is from VS2013)

Comment: haha, yeap, exactly, I spent like 10min in a new VS installation to find how to disable it :D such a waste of vertical space...

Comment: Fixes bug in Visual Basic 2015 on Azure VM.

Comment: Was checked under "All Languages" had to check in "Basic" to make it appear.

Comment: Spent 10 minutes in new VS install trying to enable this. Best short functionality in VS!!!

Comment: This is still a "feature" in VS2019. If the class and method dropdowns are missing, toggle the Navigation Bar setting on/off/on and it should re-appear.

Comment: Still the answer for VS 2022 17.4.3

Answer (score 12):

Tools - Options - Text Editor - (choose the type of file - C#, html, etc) - General

In the bottom section of the form (The "Display" area) make sure that "Navigation Bar" is checked.

Answer (score 11):

Actually there is a bug in VS2013, where if you place VS on the monitor on the left side, and this is not your primary monitor, then the dropdowns will not work.

Comment: This bug seems to have been fixed with Visual Studio Update 3.

Comment: Also VS2015 has the same bug.

Answer (score 1):

I came here searching for a solution for javascript/node.js specifically (in VS 2013). Only by doing further search I found out that this feature has been removed (from RC) due to stability/performance reasoning and is not available anymore.

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/806325/javascript-navigation-bars-are-missing-after-upgrading-from-vs2013-pro-rc-to-rtm

Also, I did not see this added again through either node tools or web essentials.

Answer (score 0):

In VS2015 I just had to toggle this setting off then back on again to get the navigation bar back.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a list of javascript functions that works similar to the navigation bar in the VB or C# pages then search for the extension inside Tools > Extensions and Updates...

Javascript Map Parser

You have to add in aspx into the pages is parses but it's exactly what I needed to quickly find functions in a big section of Javascript I had.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you in code behind file.

In my case I was looking at code (VB) server side code inside .aspx page, and the dropdown only for code behind files (.aspx.vb or aspx.cs)