# Visual Studio 2013 navigation bar lost

Tags: visual-studio-2013, navigationbar

I recently moved up from MSVS2010 to 2013.
Until now, I was loving 2013... However, I locked my PC and went to make coffee - upon my return, my navigation bar had randomly disappeared!
I'm not sure if what I mean is actually called the "Navigation bar" - by this, I mean the drop-down list in the top right corner that allows you to jump between functions/subroutines etc. really easily.

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1441207/class-name-and-method-name-dropdown-list-is-missing-visual-studio-setting) post which mentioned changing the setting in options (the navigation bar option is checked in my options). It also mentions that MSVS2013 has a **bug** that removes the bar when using an external monitor on the left of your native monitor, this is the case for me - but I have disconnected the monitor, restarted my PC and tried again - no joy!
The image below shows where the bar normally goes, forgive my crude censorship. 
[image: This shows where the bar is normally]

Any help is more than welcome, thanks.

Comment: It's also worth noting that since this happened, I also lost my intellisense! Unfortunately, I see no other way around this than a complete re-installation. I'll update if successful.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1441207/class-name-and-method-name-dropdown-list-is-missing-visual-studio-setting