# Class, Members - bar not visible for VB in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio

The dropdown bar (not sure what it is called) that appears at top of Visual Studio editor which shows Type name, members and methods is not visible for VB in Visual Studio 2015. Same is visible for C#. Is there some setting that I need to change ?

> VB

[image: VB Language - No Bar]

> C#

[image: C-Sharb - Bar]

Answer (score 3):

Tools-->Options... Text Editor-->All Languages Check "Navigation Bar."

Got the answer at [class name and method name dropdown list is missing (visual studio setting)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1441207/class-name-and-method-name-dropdown-list-is-missing-visual-studio-setting)