# VS 2015 Code Designer

Tags: vb.net, window, visual-studio-2015, designer

I am missing the drop down lists used to navigate between form events in the VB code editor.

[image]

I am trying to get the event windows back into the code designer.

[image]

Comment: That happens when you open a source file which is not part of the project.  An example would be a call to a DLL (debug compile); if the method crashes, VS will open the file but without the dropdown navigators.

Comment: Thanks Plutonix, I guess that this is the problem as my project is part of a solution. I got the navigation to reappear by unchecking the option and rechecking it in options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[class name and method name dropdown list is missing (visual studio setting)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1441207/class-name-and-method-name-dropdown-list-is-missing-visual-studio-setting)

unchecked and rechecked the "Navigation Bar"

[image]