# List of items in source file with simple navigation

Tags: visual-studio-2015

Can't find something like "tagbar window" in visual studio or his alternatives.

Tagbar - clickable short summary of the active source file. List of methods, fields, enumeration etc...

Screenshot for explanation (in Vim). Tagbar is at right side.
[image]

So, how c# developers navigate inside huge class files?

Answer (score 1):

There's a dropdown menu to the top right of your code called the [Navigation Bar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/9w13x3hh%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). If it's missing try the [instructions in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1441207/class-name-and-method-name-dropdown-list-is-missing-visual-studio-setting).

Comment: Drop menu not so convenient, but better than nothing.

Answer (score 1):

You can expand a file in Solution Explorer to see its methods and members:

[image]

See also [Viewing the Structure of Code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/whks02wf.aspx) describing Class View, Call Hierarchy, Object Browser and Code Definition Window.